# angular-strap $modal is not defiend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

I am trying to use the modal service .
What is wrong with the following :

http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/651/

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/0.7.4/angular-strap.min.js"></script>

<div class="content" ng-app="contacts" ng-controller="ContactsController">
</div>

angular.module('contacts', ['$strap.directives'])
.controller('ContactsController', function ($scope) {

var modalPromise = $modal({template: '/js/app/views/elements/modal-welcome.html', persist: true, show: false, backdrop: 'static', scope: $scope});

// Toggle modal
$scope.showModalViaService = function() {

    $q.when(modalPromise).then(function(modalEl) {
        modalEl.modal('show');
    });
};})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your fiddle. There were 2 issue.

- The $modal service has to be injected.     `.controller('ContactsController', function ($scope,$modal) {`
- The version of Angular has some problem. I changed it to 1.1.5 -> You can also try 1.0.8.

See the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/EQXg7/

Now the problem with the path of your modal template but that can be fixed by providing the right path.